# How to use both left and right yAxes in ng2-chart?

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

This is my [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-with-line-khus4j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

[image: demo]

**Output**: I want line is follow right yAxes

I set yAxes by ID but it's not working. The percent line is still follow left yAxes.
where am I wrong?

```
datasets = [
  {
    data: [3, 10, 4],
    label: 'Application number',
    yAxesID: 'y-axis-l',
  },
  {
    data: [2, 4, 1],
    label: 'Applied',
    yAxesID: 'y-axis-l',
  },
  {
    data: [66.66, 40, 25],
    label: 'Percent',
    type: 'line',
    yAxesID: 'y-axis-r',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
  },
];
options = {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          id: 'y-axis-l',
          position: 'left',
          // ...
        },
        {
          id: 'y-axis-r',
          position: 'right',
          // ...
        },
      ],
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `yAxesID` by `yAxisID` inside your `datasets` and it will work as expected.

```
datasets = [
  {
    data: [3, 10, 4],
    label: 'Application number',
    yAxisID: 'y-axis-l'
  },
  {
    data: [2, 4, 1],
    label: 'Applied',
    yAxisID: 'y-axis-l'
  },
  {
    data: [66.66, 40, 25],
    label: 'Percent',
    type: 'line',
    yAxisID: 'y-axis-r',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
  },
];
```

Please take a look at your amended [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-with-line-zexvmh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) and see how it works.

Comment: Good answer but it is not working in v5?